# Document Ready + Focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, focus

I'm trying to learn some JS / Jquery and trying to implementing some functions toghether to learn in how to do it.

My goal is to make a progress bar, that only fires up if while the tab is ative. This function should be thriggered when document ready or after X seconds.

I've already got some of the achievements but it's hard to complete it.

My actual code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(window).focus(function(){
  var progress = $(".loading-progress").progressTimer({
  timeLimit: 15,
  onFinish: function () {
   alert("ok");
  },
  showHtmlSpan: false,
  });
     });
});
```

```html
<div class="loading-progress"></div>
```

The main problems:
1 - If I open the page, I need to change the tab and come back to focus and start. The point it's to start right away since the tab is focused.
2 - It doesn't stop if change tab. If I change tab, why the code keeps running since I put into the focus windows code?
3 - I have no clue in how to make it wait X seconds or document ready.

Can someone help me trying to figure it out these 3 aspects? Thanks.

Comment: Please supply your HTML, the JavaScript alone is not enough to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Added HTML... It's very simple cause I just want to do progress bar.

Comment: Ah, you're referring to browser tabs. You'll need to use `$(window).blur(function () { ... });` to detect when the tab focus has changed from your page.

Comment: I've tried to make that too, but have no clue in how to stop the "focus code" while it's "blur"...Tried to make a var time for the progress  timer and when the tab is blur add 1 seconds to the timer, but with no luck.

Comment: Presumably the plugin you are using (progressTimer) has methods for pausing/resuming etc. If so, use those methods inside of `$(window).blur` (pause) and `$(window).focus` (resume). Call your initialisation function (what is in your question) outside of either of the blur/focus calls.

Comment: I already tried that but it only have the OnFinish event. I can't fin any progress timer ( countdown progress bar ) that have those functions that could be easy to use...

Comment: Then you will need to write your own pause/resume functionality into the plugin. Do you have a link to the plugin you are using?

Comment: Yes... It's from https://github.com/tnory56/jquery-progressTimer

Comment: Apologies for the delay. It doesn't look like this plugin supports pause/resume methods. You may wish to add your own methods into this plugin (how to do so is out of the scope of your question) or find an alternative plugin.